# How to remove impact of regression variable/coefficient when using Random Forest regression (or other ensemble models)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, random-forest

I am estimating a regression problem (product pricing), and the challenge is to remove the impact of one aspect from the model. For instance, if I am pricing laptops, I would like to separate the impact of the hardware specs (RAM, screen size, etc.) from the impact of brand (Apple, HP, etc.)

I am more used to linear regression models of the form:

```
price = a*(hardware specs) + b*(brand specs)
```

Where I could define an adjusted predicted price as price - b*(brand specs).

However in my prediction testing, RF Regression performs by far the best, and it doesn't create coefficients like a linear model does.

What are my options here for a similar approach, to removing an aspect of the regression that is, in fact, predictive?

Answer (score 1):

If the features are completely independent (or you really only care about two cases, one with all features and one with the given feature removed, as the question seems to ask), remove the feature, re-train your classifier, and get a score difference between the two models.

However, one thing to keep in mind is that if any remaining features are correlated with the feature in question you won't get the full explanatory power of it, since the model is already getting some of that information.  You should also look at a covariance matrix of your features to see if that's the case.

Comment: Agreed - I'd say that is the conundrum. I will definitely try the above approach, but you hit it on the head: I suspect there is correlation there that is worth capturing.